# UIScrollView. How Can I Tell Zoom Out From Zoom In?

Tags: ios5, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

On iOS I have a UIScrollView subclass. During a zoom gesture I need to distinguish zoom-out from zoom-in. What is the best way to do this?

Thanks,
Doug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `UIScrollViewDelegate`'s `scrollViewWillBeginZooming:withView:`, store the current `zoomScale` of your `UIScrollView`; compare the stored value to the `zoomScale` in the `scrollViewDidEndZooming:withView:atScale:` to determine if it was a zoom in or a zoom out. If the value has increased, it was a zoom in; otherwise, it was a zoom out.

Comment: Close. Actually I need realtime updates to minify/magnify status so I update store zoom in scrollViewDidScroll:. Cheers.